# Linq query only returning 1 row

Tags: linq, select, join

```
Dim ds = From a In db.Model
           Join b In db.1 On a.id Equals b.ID
           Join c In db.2 On a.id Equals c.ID
           Join d In db.3 On a.id Equals d.ID
           Join f In db.4 On a.id Equals f.ID
   Select a.id, a.Ref, a.Type, a.etc
```

Above is my linq query. At the moment I am only getting the first row from the db returned when there are currently 60 rows. Please can you tell me where I am going wrong and how to select all records.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

When I take out all the joins like so:

```
 Dim ds = From a In db.1, b In db.2, c In db.3, d In db.4, f In db.5
Select a.id, a.Ref, a.type, b.etc, c.etc, d.etc
```

I get a system.outofmemory exception!

Comment: How are you using the result of the query ?

Comment: I am binding to a gridview and then exporting to xls

Comment: If you run the corresponding SQL (with all the joins), do you get all 60 rows?

Comment: So, you have 60 "a" rows that are referenced each by a single row at least of the "b", "c", "d" and "f" ?

Comment: Akram, I have 60 a rows. They may or may not have a b,c,d,f row depending on user choices

Comment: The LINQ query will return rows that have _all_ of them set.

Comment: @Phill: The query wont return any row that is not referenced by all of b, c, d and f ..

Comment: is there another method I can use to get them all?

Comment: @Akram, when i omit the joins I get a system.outofmemory exception. is my syntax (updated question above) ok?

Comment: @Phill: What you want is to return the "a"s that are referenced by one of "b", "c", "d" or "f" at least ??

Comment: i Want to return all a's. then if there is a b,c,d,f associated i would like to return them to.

Comment: @Phill: Jon Skeet's answer is what you want then ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only going to get a row produced when *all* of the joins match - in other words, when there's a row from `Model` with an AP, an Option, a Talk and an Invoice. My guess is that there's only one of those.

LINQ does an inner join by default. If you're looking for a left outer join (i.e. where a particular row may not have an Invoice, or a Talk etc) then you need to use a group join, usually in conjunction with `DefaultIfEmpty`.

I'm not particularly hot on VB syntax, but [this article](http://codeguru.earthweb.net/vb/vb_linq/article.php/c15057/) looks like it's what you're after.

Comment: That sounds like what I am looking for!

Comment: Thanks jon that lead me to the solution :0)